# Various pointcut expression scopes trigger multiple advice calls unexpectedly

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, pointcut

## Background

Logging a project using aspects such that all methods, classes, and constructors that are marked with the `@Log` annotation have information written to a log file.

## Problem

Methods appear to be called recursively one-level deep, but the code does not show any such recursive relationship.

### Actual

Logged results:

```
2018-09-25 12:17:29,155 |↷|   EmailNotificationServiceBean#createPayload([SECURE])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,155 |↷|     EmailNotificationServiceBean#createPayload([{service.notification.smtp.authentication.password=password, mail.smtp.port=25, service.notification.smtp.authentication.username=dev@localhost, mail.mime.allowutf8=true, mail.smtp.auth=false, mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false, mail.smtp.timeout=10000, mail.smtp.host=localhost}])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,193 |↷|       EmailPayloadImpl#<init>([{service.notification.smtp.authentication.password=password, mail.smtp.port=25, service.notification.smtp.authentication.username=dev@localhost, mail.mime.allowutf8=true, mail.smtp.auth=false, mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false, mail.smtp.timeout=10000, mail.smtp.host=localhost}])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,193 |↷|         EmailPayloadImpl#validate([SECURE])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,194 |↷|           EmailPayloadImpl#validate([{service.notification.smtp.authentication.password=password, mail.smtp.port=25, service.notification.smtp.authentication.username=dev@localhost, mail.mime.allowutf8=true, mail.smtp.auth=false, mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false, mail.smtp.timeout=10000, mail.smtp.host=localhost}, SMTP connection and credentials])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,195 |↷|         EmailPayloadImpl#setMailServerSettings([SECURE])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,196 |↷|           EmailPayloadImpl#setMailServerSettings([{service.notification.smtp.authentication.password=password, mail.smtp.port=25, service.notification.smtp.authentication.username=dev@localhost, mail.mime.allowutf8=true, mail.smtp.auth=false, mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false, mail.smtp.timeout=10000, mail.smtp.host=localhost}])
```

### Expected

Expected logged results:

```
2018-09-25 12:17:29,155 |↷|   EmailNotificationServiceBean#createPayload([SECURE])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,193 |↷|     EmailPayloadImpl#<init>([SECURE])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,193 |↷|       EmailPayloadImpl#validate([SECURE])
2018-09-25 12:17:29,195 |↷|       EmailPayloadImpl#setMailServerSettings([SECURE])
```

## Code

The logging aspect:

```java
@Aspect
public class LogAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public @Log( secure = true ) *.new(..))")
    public void loggedSecureConstructor() { }

    @Pointcut("execution(@Log( secure = true ) * *.*(..))")
    public void loggedSecureMethod() { }

    @Pointcut("execution(public @Log( secure = false ) *.new(..))")
    public void loggedConstructor() { }

    @Pointcut("execution(@Log( secure = false ) * *.*(..))")
    public void loggedMethod() { }

    @Pointcut("execution(* (@Log *) .*(..))")
    public void loggedClass() { }

    @Around("loggedSecureMethod() || loggedSecureConstructor()")
    public Object logSecure(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return log(joinPoint, true);
    }

    @Around("loggedMethod() || loggedConstructor() || loggedClass()")
    public Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return log(joinPoint, false);
    }

    private Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, boolean secure) throws Throwable {
        final Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
        final Logger log = getLogger(signature);

        final String className = getSimpleClassName(signature);
        final String memberName = signature.getName();
        final Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        final CharSequence indent = getIndentation();
        final String params = secure ? "[SECURE]" : Arrays.deepToString(args);

        log.trace("\u21B7| {}{}#{}({})", indent, className, memberName, params);

        try {
            increaseIndent();

            return joinPoint.proceed(args);
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            final SourceLocation source = joinPoint.getSourceLocation();
            log.warn("\u2717| {}[EXCEPTION {}] {}", indent, source, t.getMessage());
            throw t;
        } finally {
            decreaseIndent();
            log.trace("\u21B6| {}{}#{}", indent, className, memberName);
        }
    }
```

The `Log` interface definition:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface Log {
    boolean secure() default false;
}
```

The decompiled service bean:

```java
@Log
public class EmailNotificationServiceBean
implements EmailNotificationService {

    @Log(secure = true)
    @Override
    public EmailPayload createPayload(Map<String, Object> settings) throws NotificationServiceException {
        Map<String, Object> map = settings;
        JoinPoint joinPoint = Factory.makeJP((JoinPoint.StaticPart)ajc$tjp_2, (Object)this, (Object)this, map);
        Object[] arrobject = new Object[]{this, map, joinPoint};
        return (EmailPayload)LogAspect.aspectOf().logSecure(new EmailNotificationServiceBean$AjcClosure7(arrobject).linkClosureAndJoinPoint(69648));
    }
```

The payload implementation:

```java
@Log
public class EmailPayloadImpl extends AbstractPayload implements EmailPayload {

    @Log(secure = true)
    public EmailPayloadImpl(final Map<String, Object> settings)
                    throws NotificationServiceException {
        validate(settings, "SMTP connection and credentials");
        setMailServerSettings(settings);
    }

    @Log(secure = true)
    private void validate(final Map<String, Object> map, final String message)
                    throws NotificationServiceException {
        if (map == null || map.isEmpty()) {
            throwException(message);
        }
    }

    @Log(secure = true)
    private void setMailServerSettings(final Map<String, Object> settings) {
        this.mailServerSettings = settings;
    }
```

## Question

What is causing:

- the `secure = true` constructor annotation attribute to be ignored; and
- the `validate` and `setMailServerSettings` methods to be called and logged twice (once securely and once not)?

I suspect the issues are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

To fix duplication issue need to adjust `loggedClass()` pointcut definition:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* (@Log *) .*(..)) && !@annotation(Log)")
public void loggedClass() { }
```

Please also find a link to *Proof of concept* in the **Additional information** section.

---

### Explanation:

Issue related to join points (defined by `@Pointcut` annotation), their patterns cross each other - and this is the reason of duplication in the logs.

In our case all `@Pointcut`s named descriptive enough, e.g.:

- `loggedClass()` covers all methods in the classes annotated by `@Log`.
- `loggedSecureMethod()` covers all methods annotated by `@Log(secure = true)`. Others remain are similar to this one, so let's ignore them for explanation.

So in case when `EmailPayloadImpl` is annotated with `@Log` and `EmailPayloadImpl.validate()` is annotated with `@Log(secure = true)` - we will have 2 active join points: one *secure* and one *non-secure*. And this will cause adding 2 log entries.

---

Assuming that we want to introduce priority in the annotations, i.e. **method-level annotation should overwrite class-level one** - the simplest way will be just to avoid crossing join point patterns.

So we will need to have 3 groups for methods:

1. Methods annotated with `@Log(secure = true)` = `loggedSecureMethod()`
2. Methods annotated with `@Log` = `loggedMethod()`
3. Methods without `@Log` annotation, but within a class annotated with `@Log`, which is:

   ```
   @Pointcut("execution(* (@Log *) .*(..)) && !@annotation(Log)")
   public void loggedClass() { }
   ```

---

### Additional information:

1. In case it will be needed to handle also `@Log(secure = true)` on the class level - need to add additional join point similar to `loggedClass()` of course.
2. Added [Proof of concept >>](https://github.com/marme1ad/spring-aspectj-annotationspriority) in the *GitHub*

Answer (score 1):

Basically your example has two issues which are causing the the duplication and the "ignoring" of the secured annotation.

First of all you have a `@Log` class level annotation in `EmailPayloadImpl` and a pointcut `@Pointcut("execution(* (@Log *) .*(..))")` named `loggedClass` which basically applies log on all of the class methods including the constructors. So that means that any method call on `EmailPayloadImpl` will end up with insecure log as the default value for `secure` attribute is `false` in `Log` annotation.

Second issue is the fact that your pointcuts for constructors are not correct that is why the `secure = true` is ignored. You are using the visibility keywords which is not correct when creating pointcuts for constructors. So the pointcut

```
@Pointcut("execution(public @Log( secure = true ) *.new(..))")
public void loggedSecureConstructor() { }
```

Should be changed to

```
@Pointcut("execution(@Log( secure = true ) *.new(..))")
public void loggedSecureConstructor() { }
```

The only difference is removal of the `public` visibility keyword. Same should be done for `loggedConstructor()`.

> So as you constructor pointcuts were incorrect the @Log annotation on
>   the constructor was ignored as there was no pointcut which should have
>   used it. And the `@Log` on the class was just applying log for all of
>   the class methods including the constructor.

Tho make your example for you need to fix the pointcuts and remove the class level annotation.

See your a fix of your example

Lets fix the pointcuts in `LogAspect`

```
@Aspect
public class LogAspect {
@Pointcut("execution(@Log( secure = true ) *.new(..))")
public void loggedSecureConstructor() { }

@Pointcut("execution(@Log( secure = true ) * *.*(..))")
public void loggedSecureMethod() { }

@Pointcut("execution(@Log( secure = false ) *.new(..))")
public void loggedConstructor() { }

@Pointcut("execution(@Log( secure = false ) * *.*(..))")
public void loggedMethod() { }

@Pointcut("execution(* (@Log *) .*(..))")
public void loggedClass() { }

@Around("loggedSecureMethod() || loggedSecureConstructor()")
public Object logSecure(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    return log(joinPoint, true);
}

@Around("loggedMethod() || loggedConstructor() || loggedClass()")
public Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    return log(joinPoint, false);
}

private Object log(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, boolean secure) throws Throwable {
    final Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
    final Logger log = getLogger(signature);

    final String className = getSimpleClassName(signature);
    final String memberName = signature.getName();
    final Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    final CharSequence indent = getIndentation();
    final String params = secure ? "[SECURE]" : Arrays.deepToString(args);

    log.trace("\u21B7| {}{}#{}({})", indent, className, memberName, params);

    try {
        increaseIndent();

        return joinPoint.proceed(args);
    } catch (final Throwable t) {
        final SourceLocation source = joinPoint.getSourceLocation();
        log.warn("\u2717| {}[EXCEPTION {}] {}", indent, source, t.getMessage());
        throw t;
    } finally {
        decreaseIndent();
        log.trace("\u21B6| {}{}#{}", indent, className, memberName);
    }
}
```

Remove the class level `@Log` annotation

```
public class EmailPayloadImpl extends AbstractPayload implements EmailPayload {

@Log(secure = true)
public EmailPayloadImpl(final Map<String, Object> settings)
                throws NotificationServiceException {
    validate(settings, "SMTP connection and credentials");
    setMailServerSettings(settings);
}

@Log(secure = true)
private void validate(final Map<String, Object> map, final String message)
                throws NotificationServiceException {
    if (map == null || map.isEmpty()) {
        throwException(message);
    }
}

@Log(secure = true)
private void setMailServerSettings(final Map<String, Object> settings) {
    this.mailServerSettings = settings;
}
```

Comment: Than you need to change the pointcut for `loggedClass` and add the `secure = false` to it.